# Test throwing exception, but ScalaTest/SBT still showing it as a passing test?

Tags: scala, scalatest

Here is the block of code in question, the response being passed to it is irrelevant at this point in my development due to the actual method returning a stub that should not pass:

```
responseParser.parseErroredResponse(response)
      .foreach {
        failure => {
          log.debug(s"$failure")
          failure mustBe a[SubmissionFailure]
          failure.message mustEqual "There is a syntax error in one of the queries in the AQuA input"
          failure.code mustEqual "90005"
          failure.names mustEqual Seq("Account", "AccountingPeriod", "NonExistent")
          failure.queries mustEqual Seq(
            "select Id from Account",
            "select Id from AccountingPeriod",
            "select non-existent from non-existent"
          )
        }
      }
  }
```

The actual `ResponseParser.parseErroredResponse` is currently this:

```
def parseErroredResponse(response: HttpResponse)
                          (implicit mat: ActorMaterializer,
                           ec: ExecutionContext): Future[SubmissionFailure] = {
    Future(SubmissionFailure("", "", Seq(), Seq(), "", ""))
  }
```

When I run the tests from both IntelliJ and SBT, I get something like this:

```
[info] - must parse a failed response and send a `SubmissionFailure` message
[ERROR] [02/08/2018 14:40:19.508] [test-system-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] [akka.dispatch.Dispatcher] "[]" did not equal "[There is a syntax error in one of the queries in the AQuA input]"
org.scalatest.exceptions.TestFailedException: "[]" did not equal "[There is a syntax error in one of the queries in the AQuA input]"
    at org.scalatest.MatchersHelper$.indicateFailure(MatchersHelper.scala:340)
    at org.scalatest.MustMatchers$AnyMustWrapper.mustEqual(MustMatchers.scala:6742)
    at hydra.connectors.zuora.AquaActorSpec.$anonfun$new$16(AquaActorSpec.scala:265)
    at scala.util.Success.foreach(Try.scala:249)
    at scala.concurrent.Future.$anonfun$foreach$1$adapted(Future.scala:224)
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:60)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$AbstractBatch.processBatch(BatchingExecutor.scala:55)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.$anonfun$run$1(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
    at scala.runtime.java8.JFunction0$mcV$sp.apply(JFunction0$mcV$sp.java:12)
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:81)
    at akka.dispatch.BatchingExecutor$BlockableBatch.run(BatchingExecutor.scala:91)
    at akka.dispatch.TaskInvocation.run(AbstractDispatcher.scala:40)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator.scala:43)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at akka.dispatch.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

yet it is still shown to be a passing test.  I'm using the `MustMatchers` trait for assertions, any ideas what I can fix to make this test fail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem in the test is that it doesn't manage the returned `Future`, the body of the `.foreach` in this case is evaluated only once the future completes, while the test is already completed.

To manage an async computation in the test you can start from this page [Async testing](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/async_testing) in Scalatest docs.

In short a solution could be to mix-in in your test class the trait `org.scalatest.concurrent.ScalaFutures` in order to check the properties once the `Future` completes, using utility methods like `whenReady(<future>)` or `<future>.futureValue`.
An example is the following:

```
whenReady(responseParser.parseErroredResponse(response)) { failure =>

  log.debug(s"$failure")
  failure mustBe a[SubmissionFailure]
  failure.message mustEqual "There is a syntax error in one of the queries in the AQuA input"
  failure.code mustEqual "90005"
  failure.names mustEqual Seq("Account", "AccountingPeriod", "NonExistent")
  failure.queries mustEqual Seq(
    "select Id from Account",
    "select Id from AccountingPeriod",
    "select non-existent from non-existent"
  )
}
```